# Perl regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match exactly `"",` but not `,"",`
for example in this string

```
"abc","123","def","","asd","876"",345
```

I need to substitute the `"",` following the `"876"` but leave the `""` after `"def"` alone.

The regex I have right now is

```
$line =~ s/[^,]"",/",/g
```

However this substitutes the `6` from `"876"`.

Comment: You can use a *lookbehind assertion*: `(?<!,)"",` to "look behind" from the current position without to include in the match result what you are testing inside it, or use the `\K` escape sequence to start the match result at the position you want in the pattern: `(?:[^,]|^)\K"",`. Note that if you are trying to fix a badly formatted csv file, there are few chances to obtain a trusted result, but who know.

Answer (score 2):

Use a group replacement:

```
$line =~ s/([^,])"",/$1",/g
```

Or a lookbehind:

```
$line =~ s/(?<!,)"",/",/g
```

Having said that, `""` is a CSV quoted quote, it can appear inside a string. For example, this is valid: `"""abc"""`. To avoid breaking that, also exclude `"` from the lookbehind:

```
$line =~ s/(?<![,"])"",/",/g
```

Comment: There's no advantage to exclude the quote from the character class: if indeed you handle cases like `"""abc"""`, you also break cases like `"""abc""""`.

Comment: Fixed: `s/(?:\G|[^",])(?:"")*\K"",/",/g`

Comment: @ikegami very nice, yet one can have things like `"""a"",""b"""`... Don't think it's possible to parse a CSV with regex with 100% accuracy (especially a broken one).

Comment: @rustyx, Re "*yet one can have things like*", Not according to the OP. /// Re "*Don't think it's possible to parse a CSV with regex with 100% accuracy*", That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fix a broken CSV file.
Doing it with a pattern match is not the best solution.
You should try fixing it by using **Text::CSV_XS** module with **allow_loose_quotes => 1** option.

Comment: I wish I could, but since this is a production server at work, I cannot install any module I like.

Answer (score -1):

This converts the broken col to an empty col and double quotes the last column. Not quite sure if that is what your looking for but there you go.

```
use strict ;

my $line = '"abc","123","def","","asd","876"",345' ;

$line =~ s/\,{0,1}\"\"\,/\,\"\"\,/g ;
my @foo = split(/\,/,$line) ;
$foo[$#foo] =~ s/^|$/\"/g ;
$line = join ",", @foo ;

print "\n$line\n" ;
```